# Loop trough nested objects and print object keys and values on html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui

I want to create a `controlgroup` with categories (languages) and childs (checkbox). I'm getting a little confused on resources I'm finding, wheter if I should use map/filter/redude or if I should use Objects.key, Objects.value and for in loops.

I can get to loop through the childs with `map` but I can´t get to go on the outer loop.

```js
obj = [
  {
    "javascript": [
      {"product": "1234"},
      {"product": "4321"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "python": [
      {"product": "9876"}
    ]
  }
];

// This is what I'm trying
const mountControlgroup = (language) => {
  return (
    language.map( (element) => (
      `<label for="ticker_id1">${element.product}</label>
       <input type="checkbox" name="insurance" id="${element.product}">` 
    ))
  )
} 

console.log(mountControlgroup(obj))
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/bernardo0marques/3qvs87yn/32/) is a running example

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You can use both of them

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/edon2utx/20/

**HTML**

```
<div class="widget">
  <h1>Controlgroup</h1>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  var myObj = [{
      "javascript": [{
          "product": "1234"
        },
        {
          "product": "4321"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "python": [{
        "product": "9876"
      }]
    }
  ];

  function makeGroup(dObj, tObj, vert) {
    var keys = Object.keys(dObj);
    var fs = $("<fieldset>").appendTo(tObj);
    var legend = $("<legend>").html(keys[0]).appendTo(fs);
    var cg = $("<div>", {
      class: "controlgroup"
    }).appendTo(fs);
    $.each(dObj[keys[0]], function(k, v) {
      $("<label>", {
        for: "ticker-" + v.product
      }).html(v.product).appendTo(cg);
      $("<input>", {
        type: "checkbox",
        name: "insurance",
        value: v.product,
        id: "ticker-" + v.product
      }).appendTo(cg);
    });
    if (vert == undefined) {
      cg.controlgroup();
    } else {
      cg.controlgroup({
        "direction": "vertical"
      });
    }
  }

  $.each(myObj, function(i, g) {
    makeGroup(g, $(".widget"));
  });
});
```

There were many issues with your Fiddle. I corrected these first.

In regards to iterating your Object, there are lots of ways to do this. I built a function that builds one group, largely off the following template:

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>{Key}</legend>
  <div class="controlgroup">
    <label for="ticker-{Value}">{Value}/label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="insurance" value="{Value}" id="ticker-{Value}">
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

You need a `fieldset` for each group, this becomes the container for all the control elements in that group.

If you had a vertical control, you can use it like so:

```
makeGroup({ php: [{ product: 9876 }] }, $(".widget"), true);
```

The final parameter is optional. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/edon2utx/26/

Comment: what were the problems with my fiddle? Also I'm checking `.each` API and the second argument should be `element` I couldn't really get the callback over there. And lastly, how could I implement that template you mentioned?

Comment: @BernardoMarques do not confuse `$.each()` with `.each()`. They are different: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/ The Fiddle was not configured properly to load outside resources, CSS, or JavaScript. The template is simply an example of the HTML Code that is generated by jQuery in my function `makeGroup()`